# Balancing export to jaeger in openTelemetry collector

Tags: jaeger, open-telemetry

I have configuration as [documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md) says

```
exporters:
  jaeger:
    endpoint: "ipv4:firstHost:14250,secondHost:14250"
    balancer_name: "round_robin"
```

Collector produces error.
How I can configure collector to balance exporter for sending requests in different backends?

> info    exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:276      Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval.        {"component_kind": "exporter", "component_type": "jaeger", "component_name": "jaeger", "error": "failed to push trace data via Jaeger exporter: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = last connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address ipv4:firstHost:14250,secondHost:14250: too many colons in address"", "interval": "30.456378855s"}

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in golang grpc client. I used openTelemetry [load balancing](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/loadbalancingexporter) Another option - use kubernetes to balance requests to backends.